# JavaFX ImageView not refreshing

Tags: javafx, imageview

This relates to JavaFX: I have a 'Products' window which contains a TableView filled with a products list, a few buttons (Edit, Delete, Add, Search) and an ImageView with the picture of the currently selected product (this pic changes correctly on click).

Clicking on the 'Edit' button opens a new window where I can change the image file for the product and correctly saves the new pic to the file system (one note here: the new image overwrites the old one, meaning the image path/filename remains the same).

When I close this 'Edit' window, I clean the picture in the ImageView control by doing:

`imageView.setImage(null);`

and then I set the "new" image:

`imageView.setImage(new Image(path));`

Setting the image to null efectively removes the old image, however, the imageView container keeps showing the "old picture" after setting the new one. Is there any kind of chache that needs to be cleaned? How can I "tell" the ImageView container that the image has changed, even though the filename is the same?

Thanks for the help, and sorry for my bad english.

Comment: You shouldn't have to do `setImage(null)`. Just set the new Image.

Comment: You can't have a two files with the same name in the same folder. Somethings is not adding up. If you had two file with the same name in different folders, that should not hurt anything.

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Did you mean when you change the image in new edit window ,it does not changing in dashboard window,is that your issue ?

Comment: @Sedrick - I can't just set the new image since the filename remains the same. I'm looking for a way to refresh the image after changing the contents of the file on disk, not the file name. Also, I don't have two different files with the same name (on disk). I overwrite the original file, so the contents change, not the file name.

Comment: @MenaiAlaEddine - Exactly. I need the dashboard to update when I change the contents of the image file using an edit window. This update doesn't need to be done in realtime (it will be better, though), it can happen when secondary windows closes. The issue here is that what changes is the contents of the image file on disk, not the filename (the new image overwrites the old one using the same file name, so the ImageView control should refresh somehow)

Comment: It should be as simple as after you overwrite the file, recreate the `Image` and set the `ImageView` with the new `Image`.

Comment: @JuanCarlos,you need to create context class that contains shared nodes between controller,or send your node (ImageView ) of dashboard to your edit controller and apply your changes.

Comment: @JuanCarlos,I suggest to bind your image views each other.[imageProperty](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/index.html?javafx/scene/image/ImageView.html).

Answer (score 1):

After two weeks I finally found the solution:

1. Instead of saving the new image using the same file name, I now use a new filename, then update the database table and delete the old file from disk.
2. Images are not longer loaded using `imageView.setImage(new Image(path));` Instead, now I load images using:

   `File img = new File(pathObtainedFromDatabase);
   InputStream isImage = (InputStream) new FileInputStream(img);
   imageView.setImage(new Image(isImage));`

Thanks to all that tried to help.